# Import linq.js in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm building a Firefox Addon with the Add-on SDK and I need to import in my `lib/main.js` the [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library which exposes the `Enumerable` object.

This library should be imported in `lib/main.js` because what I need is a script that runs just once (as for the corresponding `background.js` file for a Chrome extension).

What I tried so far is loading linq.js as a contentScriptFile, but I get an error when trying to use the Enumerable object.

Here's my code:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("linq.js")]
});

console.log(Enumerable);
```

Which returns:

```
Message: ReferenceError: Enumerable is not defined
```

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding linq.js as a content script into a page, not importing it into the main.js file. For more on how content scripts work, please [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts).

Using your example, how this would actually work is this:

main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("linq.js"), data.url("myscript.js")]
});
```

In 'myscript.js', you could then use linq.js:

```
console.log(Enumerable);
```

At this point you could use linq.js in your code operating against the page these scripts are attached to.